# State being emptied when adding objects with useState

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that is drawing arrows that you can drag around the screen

```
 const App = () => {
     const [arrows, createArrow]=useState([<Arrow/>])
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>createArrow([...arrows, <Arrow/>])}>Add Force</button> 
            <ArrowForm arrows = {arrows} newArrow={createArrow} />
      <svg
        style={{
          border: '1px solid green',
          height: '200px',
          width: '100%',
        }}
      >
          <Grid/>
          {arrows.map((child) => child)}
      </svg>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The ArrowForm uses the newArrow function to create additional arrows and add them to the state:

```
export default function ArrowForm({arrows, newArrow}) {
    const[position, setPosition] = useState({x:0, y:0})
    return(
        <form  onSubmit={ () => {newArrow([...arrows, <Arrow />])}}>
        <label>x: 
        <input type="number" value = {position.x} onChange={e=>setPosition(e.target.value)}/>
        </label>
        <label>y: 
        <input type="number" value = {position.y} onChange={e=>setPosition(e.target.value)}/>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    )
}
```

Whenever I add an arrow using the submit button in the ArrowForm, ay previous arrows are deleted from the state object arrows. I'm not sure why this is happening. Here's a demo that shows this behavior: [FBD Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fbd-demo-lrof3?file=/src/App.js)

If it helps, here is what the Arrow object looks like:

```
import React from "react"
import {useState, useRef} from "react"
import {useSvgDnD} from "./useSVGDnD"

 const Arrow = (props) => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({x: props.x2, y: props.y2, coords: {}})
    const [handleMouseDown, handleMouseUp] = useSvgDnD(position, setPosition)

    return (
      <svg>
      <defs>
        <marker
          id="arrowhead"
          markerWidth="10"
          markerHeight="7"
          refX="0"
          refY="3.5"
          orient="auto"
        >
          <polygon points="0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
        </marker>
      </defs>
      <line
        x1={props.x}
        y1={props.y}
        x2={position.x}
        y2={position.y}
        stroke="#000"
        stroke-width="1"
        marker-end="url(#arrowhead)"
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      />
      <circle
        cx={position.x}
        cy={position.y}
        r={25}
        fill-opacity="0"
        stroke-opacity="0"
        fill="black"
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth="1"
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      />
      </svg>
    )
  }

  Arrow.defaultProps={
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    x2: 200,
    y2: 150
  }

  export default Arrow
```

Comment: Seems there is an issue with your codesandbox, it fails to run. Based on your description this has the code smell of a stale enclosure.

Comment: I'm not passing position to as a prop to the Arrow right now, and instead just using the defaultProps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrowForm` is reloading the page when the submit button is pressed. You should prevent default form action on the `onSubmit` event object.

```
<form
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    newArrow([...arrows, <Arrow />]);
  }}
>
```

I suggest also to use functional state updates so state updates correctly from the previous state.

ArrowForm.js

```
<form
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    newArrow(arrows => [...arrows, <Arrow />]);
  }}
>
```

App.js

```
<button onClick={() => createArrow(arrows => [...arrows, <Arrow />])}>
  Add Force
</button>
```